# How to get an expandable menu in magento category list

Tags: css, magento, webshop

Any idea how I can get a category menu that expand when you click on a category?
Here you can see an example at the left menu (not magento) http://www.rijwielcashencarry.nl

Is this possible with css only?

Or is there a module that can do this?

Comment: It's not possible with just css. Css doesn't support any clicking by the user, you need javascript to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it (it costs €30) but [here](http://magentomechanics.com/collapsable-verticle-menus.html) is a module that should do what you want.

If you're more of a DIY guy, check this [Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/how_to_create_a_vertical_left_hand_menu) that explains almost everything needed to get a vertical menu. With a bit of JavaScript you should be able to get collapsing submenus easily.